# Magento Rest API - white space sku issue

Tags: magento, magento2, rest

**Issue**

Unable to get update price via REST API due to white space in the sku

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Create a product with SKU containing white space, eg. 'BAH SB'
2. Query Magento instance via REST API /rest/V1/products/BAH SB
3. Observe response

**I tried URL Encoding**:

> /rest/V1/products/BAH%20SB
>
> /rest/V1/products/BAH+SB

but didn't work.

Any Help?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296117/49715

Answer (score 0):

Magento can handle white spaces in the SKU.
I just tried and the product came normally.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eaJ5.png)